# How to get Client Secret Key Expiry date in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I have applications registered in Azure AD Tenant and these applications have clientid and secret. 
I have a requirement to get the azure application credentials expiry date. I am using azure sdk for java in my application.
How can we get the client secret expiry date using java ?

I have googled for it but didn't find any useful links. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get secret expiry date in your Java application, you can call the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to get the application. Then the application's property [passwordCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta) has the information. For example

**Register a new application using the Azure portal**

1. Sign in to the Azure portal using either a work or school account or
   a personal Microsoft account.
2. If your account gives you access to more than one tenant, select your account in the top right corner, and set your portal session to the Azure AD tenant that you want.
3. In the left-hand navigation pane, select the Azure Active Directory service, and then select App registrations > New registration.

**Configure Microsoft Graph permissions you need for your application**
[image]

**Code**

```
  //install ADAL4J get accesss token
    String clientId = "your application id";
    String appKey = "your client secret";
    String tenantId = "your tenant id";
    String authority =String.format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/",getTenantContextId())
    String resourceUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    ExecutorService service =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    AuthenticationContext context = ew AuthenticationContext(authority, false, service); 
    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(
                clientId, appKey);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(resourceUrl, clientCred, null);
     AuthenticationResult result = future.get();
    
    //Call Microsoft graph api
   String stringUrl ="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=appId eq '{ApplicationId}'";
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl.replaceAll(" ","%20"));

         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.getAccessToken());
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (httpResponseCode == 200 ) {
            BufferedReader in = null;
             StringBuilder response;

                in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                response = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }

                in.close();
            JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-beta)

### Update

Please use the following code to get access token

```
String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);
        ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        String resourceId ="https://graph.microsoft.com";
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(resourceId, cred, null);
        AuthenticationResult result = future.get();
        String accesstoken = result.getAccessToken();
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, what is getTenantContextId() method here. I tried this example as it is by giving authority as "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantIdValue/oauth2/authorize". But I am always getting 401 response code with error saying java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: URL.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I tried the updated answer. Now I am getting response code as 403. java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:URL.

Comment: @rupa Please check if your Azure AD application has enough graph api permissions. It should have "Application.ReadWrite.All" and " Directory.Read.All" permissions. For more details about the API, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

1. [Add an auth file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md)(optional but suggested, you can directly use client id and secret in your code)
2. [Use Azure Management Libraries for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
    <version>1.24.2</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Code sample

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File credFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("./others/xh.auth").getPath());

        ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = ApplicationTokenCredentials.fromFile(credFile);
        Azure.Authenticated authenticated = Azure.configure().authenticate(credentials);

        String appObjectId = "b48bc188-ff55-4655-a1d0-b8590c179a99";

        ActiveDirectoryApplication application = authenticated.activeDirectoryApplications().getById(appObjectId);

        Map<String, PasswordCredential> map = application.passwordCredentials();

        for ( Map.Entry<String,PasswordCredential> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            PasswordCredential value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Name -> " + key + " ; End date -> " + value.endDate().toString());
        }

    }
```

4. Output

```
    Name -> t o m  ; End date -> 2299-12-30T16:00:00.000Z
    Name-> 3ba9bb7b-5251-4bbb-a373-658e346eb44d ; End date -> 2299-12-30T16:00:00.000Z
    Name-> p o s t m a n  ; End date -> 2299-12-30T16:00:00.000Z
```

**Update:**

You can get the application object id from portal:

[image]

**Update2:**

There is a getByName method:

```
ActiveDirectoryApplication byName = authenticated.activeDirectoryApplications().getByName("");
```

But there is a known problem. As the applications registered in Azure AD could have the same name. This method will not get a correct 
 ActiveDirectoryApplication instance as you expected. You will always get the first one in the list. (Actually, with REST API and filter, you will get a list too)

But, if you have created all the applications with different names, then you can use the getByName method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is an appObjectId here ? Is it an objectId of the registered application or applicationId? I have applicationId and secret in my application but I don't have objectId.

Comment: Yes, in the portal we have but how can I get it using java. I can't hardcode the objectId value as this should be dynamic.

Comment: @ Jack Jia  thanks for your update, we are able to get the password credentials by using Object ID. If we have multiple password credentials as you shown the output as above, is there any way to get the specific password credentials end-date.